# No Standard Found Matching That Query Django

Tags: django

I am working on a Django project, everything was working smoothly when I was on it but then when I opened the same project and running it in the server it throws errors of page note found yet its there in the code. Here is the code
this is the urls.py page for my django app

```
from django.urls import path
from student import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

app_name = 'student'

urlpatterns = [
path('studentclick', views.studentclick_view),
path('studentlogin', LoginView.as_view(template_name='student/studentlogin.html'),name='studentlogin'),
path('studentsignup', views.student_signup_view,name='studentsignup'),
path('student-dashboard', views.student_dashboard_view,name='student-dashboard'),
path('student-exam', views.student_exam_view,name='student-exam'),
path('take-exam/<int:pk>', views.take_exam_view,name='take-exam'),
path('start-exam/<int:pk>', views.start_exam_view,name='start-exam'),

path('calculate-marks', views.calculate_marks_view,name='calculate-marks'),
path('view-result', views.view_result_view,name='view-result'),
path('check-marks/<int:pk>', views.check_marks_view,name='check-marks'),
path('student-marks', views.student_marks_view,name='student-marks'),

path('standard-list', views.StandardListView.as_view(), name='standard-list'),
#path('',views.StandardListView.as_view(),name='standard_list'),
path('<slug:slug>', views.SubjectListView.as_view(), name='subject_list'),
path('<str:standard>/<slug:slug>/', views.LessonListView.as_view(),name='lesson_list'),
path('<str:standard>/<str:slug>/create/',views.LessonCreateView.as_view(), name='lesson_create'),
path('<str:standard>/<str:subject>/<slug:slug>/', views.LessonDetailView.as_view(),name='lesson_detail'),
path('<str:standard>/<str:subject>/<slug:slug>/update',views.LessonUpdateView.as_view(),name="lesson_update"),
path('<str:standard>/<str:subject>/<slug:slug>/delete',views.LessonDeleteView.as_view(),name='lesson_delete'),

path('student-notes',views.notes, name='student-notes'), 
path('delete_note/<int:pk>',views.delete_note,name='delete-notes'),
path('notes_detail/<int:pk>',views.NotesDetailView.as_view(),name='notes-detail'),
path('student-dictionary', views.dictionary, name='student-dictionary'),
path('student-books',views.Books, name='student-books'),
path('student-todos',views.todo, name='student-todos'),

]
```

and this is my views.py file code

```
def Books(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Dashboardform(request.POST)
        text = request.POST['text']
        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+text
        r = requests.get(url)
        answer = r.json()
        result_list = []
        for i in range(10):
            result_dic ={
                'title': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo']['title'],
                'subtitle': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo'].get('subtitle'),
                'description': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo'].get('description'),
                'count': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo'].get('pageCount'),
                'categories': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo'].get('catergories'),
                'rating': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo'].get('pageRating'),
                'thumbnail': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo'].get('imageLinks').get('thumbnail'),
                'preview': answer['items'][i]['volumeInfo'].get('previewLink'),
            }
            result_list.append(result_dic)
            context = {
                'form':form,
                'results':result_list,
            }
        return render(request,'student/student_books.html',context)    
    else:
        form = Dashboardform()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'student/student_books.html',context)


def dictionary(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Dashboardform(request.POST)
        text = request.POST['text']
        url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/"+text
        r = requests.get(url)
        answer = r.json()
        try:
            phonetics = answer[0]['phonetics'][0]['text'],
            audio = answer[0]['phonetics'][0]['audio'],
            definition = answer[0]['meanings'][0]['definitions'][0]['definition'],
            example = answer[0]['meanings'][0]['definitions'][0]['example'],
            synonyms = answer[0]['meanings'][0]['definitions'][0]['synonyms'],
            context ={
                'form':form,
                'input' : text,
                'phonetics' : phonetics,
                'audio': audio,
                'definition': definition,
                'example': example,
                'synonyms' : synonyms,
            }
        except:
            context = {
                'form':form,
                'input' : '',
            }
        return render(request, 'student/student_dictionary.html', context)

    else:
        form = Dashboardform()
        context = {'form':form}
    return render (request,'student/student_dictionary.html', context)


detailView = generic.DetailView
def notes(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = NotesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            notes = Notes(user=request.user,title=request.POST['title'],description=request.POST['description'],)
            notes.save()
        messages.success(request,f"Notes added from {request.user.username} successfully")
    else:
        form = NotesForm()

    notes = Notes.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'notes': notes, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'student/student_notes.html', context)

@login_required
def delete_note (request,pk=None): 
    Notes.objects.get(id=pk).delete()
    return redirect ('student-notes'),

class NotesDetailView (detailView):
    model = Notes


def todo(request):
    return render(request, 'student/student_todos.html')



class StandardListView(ListView):
    context_object_name ='standards'
    model = Standard
    template_name = "student/standard_list_view.html"


class SubjectListView(DetailView):
    context_object_name ='standards'
    model = Standard
    template_name = "student/subject_list_view.html"


class LessonListView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'subjects'
    model = Subject
    template_name = "student/lesson_list_view.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        # Override get_object to get the Subject based on the 'slug' URL parameter
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Subject, slug=slug)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Retrieve the subject object from the context
        subject = self.object

        # Get the lessons for the subject and pass them to the template
        context['lessons'] = Lesson.objects.filter(subject=subject)
        return context


class LessonDetailView(DetailView, FormView):
    context_object_name ='lessons'
    model = Lesson
    template_name = "student/lesson_detail_view.html"
    form_class = CommentForm
    second_form_class = ReplyForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LessonDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class()
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class()
        # context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(id=self.object.id)
        return context
```

And the error code is like that

```
Page not found (404)
No standard found matching the query
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/student-notes
Raised by:  student.views.SubjectListView
Using the URLconf defined in onlinexam.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
teacher/
student/ studentclick
student/ studentlogin [name='studentlogin']
student/ studentsignup [name='studentsignup']
student/ student-dashboard [name='student-dashboard']
student/ student-exam [name='student-exam']
student/ take-exam/<int:pk> [name='take-exam']
student/ start-exam/<int:pk> [name='start-exam']
student/ calculate-marks [name='calculate-marks']
student/ view-result [name='view-result']
student/ check-marks/<int:pk> [name='check-marks']
student/ student-marks [name='student-marks']
student/ standard-list [name='standard-list']
student/ <slug:slug> [name='subject_list']
The current path, student/student-notes, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

And what is bothering when it throws the error it does not display all the urls in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

try add "/" at end :

```
path('student-notes/',views.notes, name='student-notes'),
```

Comment: Thank you but already tried this out but it not working

Comment: hm strange, have you restarted server after you added slash?

Comment: I tried all that but it stilling breaking

Answer (score 0):

After a long spell i realized that URL patterns are evaluated sequentially, and the first matching pattern is used. In this case, the URL pattern for student/slug:slug is catching the URL before the pattern for student-books has a chance to be matched.So by moving the URL patterns for student-books, notes, delete_note, notes_detail, and student-dictionary above the pattern for student/slug:slug, it ensures that these patterns will be matched correctly before the more generic slug:slug pattern.